# Hibernate SQLQuery list method returns Object instead of object array

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I have this strange behavior with Hibernate `SQLQuery.list()` method.

**Following is the description of the issue:**

I have a sql select query which retrieves only single column(group) from the database (i.e., `select group from peopleGroup where groupid = 10`)
And i'm recieving the result of the above list in List of Object array
 i.e,

```
SQLQuery hQuery = session.createSQLQuery("select group from peopleGroup where groupid = 10");
List<Object[]> result = (List<Object[]>)hQuery.list();
```

Ideally, the result should contain a list of object arrays but when I inspect, 0'th index of the result contains  String object instead of an Object array.
However if I use more than one column let's say 2 columns in the select clause of the query I was able to see that 0'th index of the result as Object array i.e., `Object[2]={"group","groupid"};`

**How do I get the Object array even if I have only one column mentioned in the select clause of the query?**

Comment: You wouldn't.....

Answer (score 1):

[Docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/Query.html#list--) states:

> List list()
>
> Return the query results as a List. If the query contains multiple 
>     results per row, the results are returned in an instance of Object[].

Convert it by yourself, like so.

```
List<Object[]> l = new ArrayList<>();
for(Object o : query.list()) {
  Object[] arr = {o};
  l.add(arr);
}
```

Comment: I understand the doc now but do i have any option of achieving my goal which is though i have single column in the select clause i need to put that returned object in object array ?

Comment: Convert it by yourself. Adding an example.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a object mapper like below code

```
public class QueryMapper {
    private String group;
    //setter and getter
    }
```

And you have to change your code like below

```
SQLQuery hQuery = session.createSQLQuery("select group from peopleGroup where groupid = 10");
List<Object[]> result = (List<Object[]>)hQuery.list();

List<QueryMapper> list = new ArrayList<QueryMapper>();

        for(Object[] object: result){
            QueryMapper queryMapper = new QueryMapper();
            if(object[0]!=null){
                queryMapper.setGroup((String)object[2]);
            }
            list.add(queryMapper);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

All i wanted is to fix the **ClassCastException** which was caught during the assignment of result.get(0) to the container i.e., container = result.get(0);

Since the value returned by mentioned list() method contains object in case of single column in the select clause of the query and i won't be allowed to cast from certain object to Object[](Object array).
Instead i have tried a work around like below

Already existing code

```
SQLQuery hQuery = session.createSQLQuery("select group from peopleGroup where groupid = 10");
List<Object[]> result = (List<Object[]>)hQuery.list();
Object[] container = result.get(0);
```

now i have put condition like below to decide how to assign value to the `Object[]`

```
SQLQuery hQuery = session.createSQLQuery("select group from peopleGroup where groupid = 10");
List<Object[]> result = (List<Object[]>)hQuery.list();
Object[] container = null;
if(result.get(0) instanceof Object[])
   container = result.get(0);
else {
     container = new Object[1];
     container[0] = result.get(0);
      }
```

The above solution seems working in my case !